# How to find the summation of the above series without using any calculator?

Tags: summation

[image]

How to find the summation of the above series upto n=49? I know that there is an Euler's formula for this summation. The formula is ln(n)+gamma, where gamma(Euler's constant)=0.05721 . But as far as I know, the formula is applicable only for large values of n. Will n=49 also work?

Comment: [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)  Your answer is $H_{50}$.  There is not a cleaner way to write this.

Comment: But how to find the summation without using calculator?

Comment: If you are looking for an *exact* result... to find the sum without a calculator you need patience... a lot of it, and do each addition manually.  If you are okay with an *approximation*, then $\ln(n)+\gamma$ or $\ln(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}$ or $\ln(n+\frac{1}{2})+\gamma$ or similar will be fine.  You can find $\ln(n)$ using any manner of old techniques from lookup tables, to slide rules, and so on... I would not recommend calculating logarithms by hand otherwise if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{p-1} \frac 1{n+1}=H_{p}$$

If $p$ is large
$$H_{p}=\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12 p^2}+\frac{1}{120
   p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^6}\right)$$ that you make shorter transforming the series into a simple Padé approximant
$$H_{p}\sim\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{18 p}{36 p^2+6 p+1}$$ whose error is $\frac{13}{2160 p^4}$.

This would give
$$H_{50}\sim\log(50)+\gamma+\frac{900}{90301}$$ which is in a absolute error of $9.64\times 10^{-10}$.